# nutch jobs failing after second round that is in fetch stage?

Tags: nutch

**Nutch jobs failing after second round that is in fetch stage** i am using emr cluster it is not throwing any error.May i know the reason.May I know what can be reasons it is stopping second round.

Comment: Without any context (stack trace, log snippets, Nutch version, command to launch it, etc.) it's impossible to guess what's going wrong. When running on Hadoop, do not forget to look into the task logs, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html. The Hadoop cluster web interface should also indicate the error.

Comment: the most probable reason could be heavy CPU and RAM utilization could lead to failure. but, again as @SebastianNagel mentioned with out log it is very tough to judge what had happened... I'm sharing my experience here --> it generally happens on heavy load you may try reducing fetcher.treads  and try running again. and make sure to monitor CPU and RAM..

Comment: bin/crawl --num-fetchers 3 --num-threads 150 $CRAWL_PATH 5
I have set above parameters.It is two node cluster running in emr.
 @kavetiraviteja

Comment: should I need to reduce the num threads.

Comment: It is not about trying various options. Instead, look into the log files to figure out what went wrong. Of course, you might try with only 2 fetchers and a lower number of threads. But in the long term you need to learn how to read log files on EMR and use monitoring tools.

Comment: I have gone through the logs but i did not any error in logs.

Comment: I have posted my logs below.@SebastianNagel

Comment: @RaviKiran your machines should have enough disk space to store HTML content as well. please check that as well

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because i did not run nohup command I was previously running with
sh filename.sh it stopped after some crawls now i am running by using the nohup sh filename.sh &.
Thanks @ Sebastian Nagel